# Remove a module from Sitefinity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

How do I remove a module from Sitefinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This only applies to Sitefinity 3.x

It depends on how far you want to go with the clean up.

If you want to simply disabled a module this can be done through the web.config look for the section:

```
 <telerik><framework><modules>
```

Simply remove the module from there and Sitefinity won't load the module.

**Optional**

The next steps are completely optional, but will fully remove a module.

Then to go further you could delete the dlls from the Bin folder that represent the modules eg Telerik.Blogs and Telerik.Blogs.Data are for the Blogs module and all the module are named in this manner.

Search for any references to the module in the web.config: eg in the sections

- SectionGroups
- Telerik
- ToolBox
- MetaFields

Then as a further clean up depending on what version of Sitefinity you are using and what module you are using.

**Some modules can't be removed though like Images and Documents and Generic Content as they are integral in the CMS Pages**

I just found also that Telerik have a [knowledgebase article](http://www.sitefinity.com/support/knowledge-base/kb-article/b1154K-bbgc-b1154T-cgh.aspx) on this.

Comment: I knew that was coming.  I've created my own module that extends Images and Documents module to replace the Upload "View" with my own to ad an image cropper. I've currently got both modules (my extended module and the original Images and Documents module) running side by side but just wanted to remove the existing module.  So basically I just want to replace the exiting module with my own.  If I inherit from all of the Telerik.Libraries types specified in the web.config do you think I could thereafter point all of these references to my implementations,or is there going to be futher problems?

Comment: If you are going to be replacing the Images and Documents module then that is a different story.  The only reason I say not to remove the Images and Documents module is because then when someone tries to insert an image the Editor Dialog will be broken.  You should be save to replace all the Web.Config references of the I&D module with your own one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about Sitefinity but i am sure you can find what you are looking for on their **[support pages](http://www.sitefinity.com/support/get-support.aspx)**, you will find videos, forums, blog post.

Also you can Submit a Support Ticket there if you didn't find a good answer.

Comment: I have submitted a support ticket, but unfortunatly Telerik only offer a 48hour response time and I need the answer to this rather more urgently.

Comment: Hope someone answer you exactly what you asked about, because 48hours are too much in urgent cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable a module by commenting it out from the < telerik/framework/modules > node in your web.config file

you should be able to remove the default module and replace it with your own, I would recommend, however that you change the application name under the < cmsEngine/Providers > node of web.config so it doesn't conflict with the existing one.